# How to start WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I didn't understand that How can I start WebRTC project.
I want to create voice chat program with WebRTC. So, I found [ How to getting start WebRTC ].

Here is the link : 
http://io13webrtc.appspot.com/#1

But, I wonder WebRTC Projects structures.
I don't understand What needs for WebRTC..
Please help me..

The WebRTC only needs HTML, JavaScripts?
How can I getting Start WebRTC sir..?

I tried to [getUserMedia()..]. But, Just only getUserMedia()..lol..
Whats next?
RTC Peer Connection? Data Channels?
And, Can implements just one HTML page ?

I don't know.
Please help sir.

Thx

Comment: You also need a server to start the connection (STUN server), may have a look at http://socket.io

Comment: Thank you Jonas..! STUN server is my private server OR public big company server ?

Comment: may have a look at https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want that：

- [Github-WebRtc-Experiment-Demos](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment)
- [Website-WebRtc-Experiment-Demos](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/)

There are many experimented WebRTC demos, I learned a lot from this.

Answer (score 0):

A good Starting point is also:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/index.htm

But be aware those Tutorials may contain some errors and outdated infos. By figuring those out you will learn a lot :)